# Deserializing XML to Custom Nested Classes in .net Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, deserialization

I'm having an issue deserializing XML from SQL Server. The XML is good; the code deserializing it is known working code; but for some reason it is only deserializing the first and second level, which has got to mean a mismatch of the class to the XML, but after staring at it I can't identify it.

This is an excerpt of the XML:

```
    <Options>
         <Countries>
             <Country ID="1" Name="Afghanistan" Code="AF" ISO="4" SubDivision="City" PostalName="Postal Code" />
             <Country ID="2" Name="Albania" Code="AL" ISO="8" SubDivision="City" PostalName="Postal Code" />
             <Country ID="3" Name="Algeria" Code="DZ" ISO="12" SubDivision="City" PostalName="Postal Code" />
             <Country ID="4" Name="American Samoa" Code="AS" ISO="16" SubDivision="City" PostalName="Postal Code" />
             <Country ID="5" Name="Andorra" Code="AD" ISO="20" SubDivision="City" PostalName="Postal Code" />
         </Countries>
         <EntityTypes>
             <EntityType ID="4" Name="Individual" />
             <EntityType ID="5" Name="Business" />
         </EntityTypes>
     </Options>
```

This is the `Options` class:

```
    namespace RecoverItWCF.Classes
    {
        [DataContract]
        [Serializable()]
        public class Options
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "Categories", IsRequired = false)]
            [XmlElement("Categories")]
            public Category[] Categories;
            [DataMember(Name = "Countries", IsRequired = false)]
            [XmlElement("Countries")]
            public Country[] Countries;
            [DataMember(Name = "EntityTypes", IsRequired = false)]
            [XmlElement("EntityTypes")]
            public EntityType[] EntityTypes;
        }
    }
```

This is the `Country` class:

```
namespace RecoverItWCF.Classes
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable()]
    public class Country
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ID", IsRequired = true)]
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Name", IsRequired = true)]
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // truncated for brevity
     }
 }
```

This is the `EntityType` class:

```
namespace RecoverItWCF.Classes
    {
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable()]
    public class EntityType
        {
        [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public Int16 ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

The `Options` element does not contain a `Categories` element (correct), and does contain a `Countries` element (correct), but the `Countries` level has nothing below it (no `Country` array) when highlighted at breakpoint, and it should have 200 `Country` elements. It also contains an `EntityTypes` element, but nothing under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Xiaoy312 for leading me down the right path. The correction needed to be made to the Options class. This got the job done.

```
    [DataMember(Name = "Countries", IsRequired = false)]
    [XmlArray("Countries")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Country")]
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `[XmlArrayItem]` attribute :

```
[XmlArrayItem("Countries", IsNullable=true, Type = typeof(Country))]
public Country[] Countries;
```

Comment: Thank you, however that didn't work. I modified the Options class. The problem appears to be in the Country and EntityType classes. I am getting one of the parent (Countries), but null values for ID and Name at a Country level and only one Country.